# Jmeter variable from response

Tags: java, jmeter

Is it posible to bind to a variable value from response and then pass it as parameter to other http request?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The earlier answer to this is hopelessly outdated.

Using the Post-Processor > Regular Expression Extractor, it is quite simple to extract any portion of the response.

The newer versions of JMeter also have Reg Exp tester options in the Listener > View Results in Tree, so you can perfect the regex till it does exactly what you want it to.

also see [Passing variable from one http request to another in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15414183/289396)

---

Earlier Answer:

<strike>It should be possible to extract an element from the response using the **Regular Expression Extractor** and store it in a variable which can be referred from further requests.</strike>

See **Extract multiple strings** on http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-jmeter/RegularExpressions and this example http://jmeter-tips.blogspot.com/2010/06/tip-12-how-to-add-http-request-sampler.html

The [official docs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) on this topic are this heading **19.5.1 __regexFunction**