# Passing variable from one http request to another in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have to pass a variable from an xpath extractor in jmeter to another http request.
How can I do this?

I want to pass the variable in header of http request.
I have saved the variable in xpath extractor as `LoginToken`.
Tried to retrieve in header of second http request as `${LoginToken}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure first that your xpath expression really returns any result.
   Set `Default Value` field in XPath Extractor to any value and use e.g. [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to view the value of LoginToken variable after XPath Extractor execution.
2. If you are using XPath Extractor to parse HTML response ensure that **Use Tidy (tolerant parser)** option is CHECKED.